# SQL Server: convert varchar into time with invalid records(seconds written as 60)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, time, type-conversion, seconds

I have time records stored in my SQL Server database as `varchar`, I am trying to convert it into time.

For example, the data is stored as `12490811`

I am using the syntax:

```
cast(convert(time, stuff(stuff(stuff(CommentAddedTime, 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 0, '.')) as time(0)) as 'CommentAddedTime'
```

But there are some invalid records stored where seconds are more than 59 like 11356000 which does not let me convert the `varchar` into time. I was wondering if we can use a Case statement or something to use like '00' for seconds when it see seconds written as 59 otherwise use the same value. I believe the syntax should be something like(I am not sure what to write in 'then' statement):

```
select 
    case 
       when substring(stuff(stuff('11356000', 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'),7,10) > 5900
          then ....
          else 
             cast(convert(time, stuff(stuff(stuff(CommentAddedTime, 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 0, '.')) as time(0))
    end as 'CommentAddedTime'
```

Please assist me what can we do with this? Or, if there is any other way to solve this problem because i can not exclude those records.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the format of the string?

Answer (score 0):

How about just using arithmetic?  SQL Server will convert strings to numbers automatically.  Then you can convert this to a time.  For the milliseconds calculation:

```
select (left(CommentAddedTime, 2) * 60 * 60 * 1000 + 
        substring(CommentAddedTime, 3, 2) * 60 * 1000 +
        substring(CommentAddedTime, 5, 2) * 1000 +
        substring(CommentAddedTime, 7, 2) * 10
       )
```

To convert this to a time:

```
select dateadd(ms,
               (left(CommentAddedTime, 2) * 60 * 60 * 1000 + 
                substring(CommentAddedTime, 3, 2) * 60 * 1000 +
                substring(CommentAddedTime, 5, 2) * 1000 +
                substring(CommentAddedTime, 7, 2) * 10
               ),
               cast(cast(0 as datetime) as time)
              )
```

(SQL Server doesn't allow `cast(0 as time)` but it does allow the double cast.)

Comment: The data is saved as 15133207(varchar) and i want to convert into (time)15:13:32 and discard the last two digits. I am using syntax:cast(convert(time, stuff(stuff(stuff(CommentAddedTime, 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 0, '.')) as time(0)) as 'CommentAddedTime'                                       But there are some invalid records like: 11356000 which doesnt convert into time, is there any way to solve this problem? May be use 00 for seconds and show the result as: 11:35:00?

Comment: @GeetanjaliSachdeva . . . Is there something about my answer that you don't understand?  Parse the string into hours, minutes, and seconds, convert these to milliseconds (or seconds if you prefer), and construct the `time` variable.

Comment: I want to convert nvarchar into time hh:mm:ss, but there is invalid data stored. For example: if the data(nvarchar) is 11356000, the result should be: 11:35:00(exclude miliseconds and show seconds as 00) How can we do that?

Comment: @GeetanjaliSachdeva . . . I would suggest that you ask another question, clearly describing what you are trying to do with sample data and desired results.